# Load-On-Demand data bound controls in RadPageView when they are selected by RadTab

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

In my webpage, I have a `RadTabStrip` containing `RadTab`:s which will decide which page view the webpage that is shown.

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="rtsTabs2" runat="server" MultiPageID="rmpMultiPage2"
    AutoPostBack="True" SelectedIndex="0" OnTabClick="rtsTabs2_TabClick">
    <Tabs>
      <telerik:RadTab Text="Page 1" PageViewID="pvPage1"  />
      <telerik:RadTab Text="Page 2" PageViewID="pvPage2" />
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

The page views are defined like this:

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="rmpMultiPage2" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="pvPage1" runat="server">
      RadGrids etc
    </telerik:RadPageView>
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="pvPage2" runat="server">
      More RadGrids etc
    </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

The page views contains numerous components that will be populated from the database.

However, I will only be interested in populate those when a page view containing them is displayed.

Which event should I listed at to determine when to populate components?

- The `OnLoad` event in `RadPageView` is triggered when the page load, regardless if the page view is shown or not.
- The `OnPreRender` event in `RadPageView` is also triggered on page load.
- The `OnNeedDataSource` event in `GridView` is the same, the event triggers when the page loads.
- Using `Visible="False"` in a `RadPageView` only results in page views that will never show up even if the corresponding `RadTab` is clicked.

Comment: There is no "Load on Demand" as coming back to a page wont make it "Reload". But there is an [exemple on Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/multipage/dynamic-pageview-creation/defaultcs.aspx) where it's show how to create on demande a pageview and add it to the multipage.
But a little question: Is the tab click Event not enought to handle the visibility?

Comment: I considered using the click event, but I am not sure if clicks is the only way of coming to a page view. Also, the selected tab can be changed programmatically.

Comment: not sure you can switch tab with keyboard. So it's only click from what I remember. And programmatically should not be a problem as you are the one making the program. An other idea is to use the `RenderSelectedPageOnly` properties, of the multipage.

Comment: I still get the "hack" feeling from listening on click events in this case.